# Mail not working in opencart

Tags: opencart2.x, opencart-module

I am using opencart 2.x . All the functions are working fine, but mails are not forwarding to admin and customer.
Mail is not forwarding to admin and customer either in order punch or in account registration in Opencart 2.x . Is there any Solution?

Comment: Did you checked if mail service are provided by your hosting?

Comment: You could test sending an email using a simple PHP script: <?PHP Mail("receiver@test.com", "Email subject", " My message"); ?> Does this work?